# Objective-C Stop counter using IF Statement

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I have a score counter using an if statement

```
 if (CGRectIntersectsRect(aliens.boundingBox, heroe.boundingBox)) {
        heroe.visible = NO;
        //HOW DO I STOP THE SCORE++ HERE?
  } 
  else {
        score++;
        [scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score]];

  }
```

I cant find a way to stop the score++

Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(aliens.boundingBox, heroe.boundingBox)) {

heroe.visible = NO;

}
else{
if(heroe.visible == yes)
score++;

[scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score]];
```

}